# Read response from a URI using spring web services

Tags: spring, spring-ws

I have a given URI , for example http://sample.com/details?q=id=11234 and when i hit this URI i am getting a response in XML format as show below.

```
<response>
  <result numFound="1">
      <Detail>
        <id>11234</id>
        <fname>abcd</fname>
        <lname>efgh</lname>
        <city>cccc</city>
        <state>ssss</state>
      </Detail>
  </result>
</response>
```

we did this by the following code and parsing the response using DOM.

```
    URL url = new URL(URI);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.connect();
    is = connection.getInputStream();
```

But we are looking to implement in spring web services,JAXB. I want to hit this URI from a java class, read the response and store the response in a Person class object(POJO). we are currently using spring 2.5. my question is how can we achieve this using spring webservices.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a SOAP service you can create a client in Spring-WS that handles all the marshalling (pojo <-> xml using jaxb).

Check out the [guides in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/index.html).